# Trying to modify a constraint in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter

I have checked the documentation provided by Oracle and found a way to modify a constraint without dropping the table.  Problem is, it errors out at modify as it does not recognize the keyword.

Using EMS SQL Manager for PostgreSQL.

```
Alter table public.public_insurer_credit MODIFY CONSTRAINT public_insurer_credit_fk1
    deferrable, initially deferred;
```

I was able to work around it by dropping the constraint using :

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."public_insurer_credit"
  DROP CONSTRAINT "public_insurer_credit_fk1" RESTRICT;

ALTER TABLE "public"."public_insurer_credit"
  ADD CONSTRAINT "public_insurer_credit_fk1" FOREIGN KEY ("branch_id", "order_id", "public_insurer_id")
    REFERENCES "public"."order_public_insurer"("branch_id", "order_id", "public_insurer_id")
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    DEFERRABLE 
    INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Comment: Why are you checking the Oracle documentation (and tagging this question with 'plsql') when you're using PostgreSQL? What's the exact error (which keyword isn't recognized)?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MODIFY"
LINE 1: Alter table public.public_insurer_credit MODIFY CONSTRAINT p...
                                                 ^
(0.359 sec)

Comment: I was a noob and checking the documentation that was provided to me.  Never occurred to me that the DBA would give me the wrong documentation.  Comment was deserved.

Comment: @MISMajorDeveloperAnyways everybody was once a noob, the only shame is forgetting that. At least you mentioned they were Oracle docs, so it was easy to figure out. The comment was not deserved.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

According to the correct manual (which is supplied by PostgreSQL, **not** by Oracle), there is no modify constraint available in the ALTER TABLE statement:

Here is the link to the correct manual:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Comment: Thank you for the link to the proper documentation.  I was supplied with the Oracle PL/SQL documentation from our DBA.  Figures.

Comment: Oracle and Oracle's PL/SQL are completely different things. The only possible reason they did that is because you are using EnterpriseDB's *Advanced Server* which has support for Oracle's PL/SQL (and other Oracle compatibility features). But then they should have given you the EnterpriseDB manual, not the Oracle manual

Comment: Best guess at downvote, the answer simply links to an external site without providing future readers an explanation of how a constraint can be changed correctly.

Answer (score 187):

There is no `ALTER` command for constraints in Postgres. The easiest way to accomplish this is to **drop** the constraint and re-add it with the desired parameters. Of course any change of the constraint will be run against the current table data.

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE t1 DROP CONSTRAINT ...
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD CONSTRAINT ...
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Beware: if I understand correctly, DDL statements take an AccessExclusive lock on the table, so if these commands take a long time, your site will grind to a halt until the commands complete.  The [documentation page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) has more details, including how to specify an index explicitly rather than having one generated automatically.

Comment: A single transaction is good. A single command is even better. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31419767/939860

Comment: As of 9.4 you can indeed alter foreign key constraints in Postgres: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

@mkurz answer below should be accepted as the new correct answer.

Answer (score 50):

As of version 9.4, PostgreSQL supports `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER CONSTRAINT` for foreign keys.

This features will `"Allow constraint attributes to be altered,
so the default setting of NOT DEFERRABLE can be altered to DEFERRABLE and back."` Looking at your question I think that is (kind of) what you have been looking for.

More detailed information and an example can be found here:
http://www.depesz.com/2013/06/30/waiting-for-9-4-alter-table-alter-constraint-for-fks/

Comment: Note that the 9.4 docs say `Currently only foreign key constraints may be altered.`!

Comment: We are at 12+, and still no way to to alter non-foreign constraints. Need to add `DEFERRABLE` to some, and can't do it without dropping/recreating them.

Answer (score 8):

ALTER CONSTRAINT would require knowing of foreign key name, which is not always convenient.

Here is function, where you need to know only table and column names.
Usage:

```
select replace_foreign_key('user_rates_posts', 'post_id', 'ON DELETE CASCADE');
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    replace_foreign_key(f_table VARCHAR, f_column VARCHAR, new_options VARCHAR) 
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $$
DECLARE constraint_name varchar;
DECLARE reftable varchar;
DECLARE refcolumn varchar;
BEGIN

SELECT tc.constraint_name, ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name, ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name 
FROM 
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
   AND tc.table_name= f_table AND kcu.column_name= f_column
INTO constraint_name, reftable, refcolumn;

EXECUTE 'alter table ' || f_table || ' drop constraint ' || constraint_name || 
', ADD CONSTRAINT ' || constraint_name || ' FOREIGN KEY (' || f_column || ') ' ||
' REFERENCES ' || reftable || '(' || refcolumn || ') ' || new_options || ';';

RETURN 'Constraint replaced: ' || constraint_name || ' (' || f_table || '.' || f_column ||
 ' -> ' || reftable || '.' || refcolumn || '); New options: ' || new_options;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Be aware: this function **won't copy** attributes of initial foreign key.
It only takes foreign table name / column name, drops current key and **replaces** with new one.

Comment: Very interesting solution