# How to alter "REFERENCES" in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, ddl, alter-table

How can I alter the reference to a table in PostgreSQL when the table name has been changed?

Say I have:

```
CREATE TABLE example1 (
   id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(100)
);

CREATE TABLE example2 (
   id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   example1fk integer REFERENCES example1 (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
```

Later I do:

```
ALTER TABLE example1 RENAME TO example3;
```

How to change the definition of the foreign key constraint?

```
example1fk integer REFERENCES example1 (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
```

Comment: Firstly, to help you search, this is called a Foreign Key Constraint. Secondly, I'm not clear what you want to do. The constraint will continue to point to the table after a rename - it would make no sense for Postgres to allow it to point at a name that didn't exist. Or do you mean you want to rename the column `example1fk` to match the new table name?

Comment: IMSoP is right: there is nothing you need to do. Postgres will take care of everything.

Comment: Did you try the rename and see what it did to the FK constraints?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Internal dependencies between tables and / or other objects are never bound to the object name. Internally, every object is stored in a catalog table and the OID (internal primary key) of the object is used for *everything* else.

Accordingly, a `FOREIGN KEY` reference is stored in the catalog tables [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html) (the constraint itself incl. its name) and [`pg_depend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-depend.html). Changing table names **will not impair functionality at all**.

The *name* of the constraint remains unchanged. You can ignore that, or you may want to rename the constraint so it's not misleading.

However, since you did not specify a constraint name at creation time, the system picked a default, which is `example2_example1fk_fkey` in your case unless the name was taken. No reference to the referenced *table* name. But the **column name** will likely have to change in your example, too. And *that* is used in the constraint name.

```
ALTER TABLE example2 RENAME example1fk TO example3fk;  -- rename column
```

In Postgres 9.2 or later you can just rename the constraint as well (as [dequis commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414462/how-to-alter-references-in-postgresql/31419767?noredirect=1#comment83981582_31419767)):

```
ALTER TABLE example2 RENAME CONSTRAINT example2_example1fk_fkey TO example2_example3fk_fkey;
```

In older versions, you have to drop and recreate the constraint to rename it, best in a single statement:

```
ALTER TABLE example2  -- rename constraint
   DROP CONSTRAINT example2_example1fk_fkey
 , ADD  CONSTRAINT example2_example3fk_fkey FOREIGN KEY (example3fk)
      REFERENCES example3 (id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

[Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

Comment: Since postgres 9.2 (2012) there's `ALTER TABLE example2 RENAME CONSTRAINT example2_example1fk_fkey TO example2_example3fk_fkey`

Comment: @dequis: Good point, I updated with a reference to your comment.